# how to connect redshift cluster using tableau 8.0 desktop

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have downloaded Tabeleau 8.0.1 desktop version. I am able to connect my local postgres database through tableau. 
But when I try to connect to the redshift cluster, I am getting an error - invlaid userid /password. I already have passed userid and password correctly. FYI, I am able to connect redshift through sqlworkbench/j, command line prompt (psql) & pgadmin III. And I already have downlaoded the redshift driver as per http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers. 
However I am not able to connect redshift cluster through tableau.

Comment: plese note i am using tablue with trial version. i don't have PRODUCT KEY. will it allow me to connect redshift cluster then ?

Comment: Does your Redshift password have any non-alpha-numeric characters?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift has a direct connect with Tableau. When you start Tableau, please use the Connect to Data option and then choose Amazon Redshift on the left. You'll see the following log-in screen. You shouldn't need to worry about drivers. Also, the Tableau trial version is the full version, so there is no limiting of features.

[image]

You can read more [here](http://www.tableausoftware.com/solutions/amazon-redshift), and watch a video. Also technical details are [here](http://www.tableausoftware.com/support/drivers). You may want to try version 8.1, which is the most recent version (also has 64 bit)